# Simple Popover View for iPhone with Storyboard

Tags: xcode, ios7, popup, uipopovercontroller, popover

I am trying to create a very simple popover view for iPhone (not iPad) to act as a Help screen for my users.  I am using a storyboard and have set my second view (the popover view) size as "Freeform" and set the size in the Size Inspector to 300 x 300.  I have a button in the first view that I would like use to segue to the popover view.  BUT HOW?

I guess while I'm at it, I'd like a button on the popover view to return to the main view.

I don't need fancy scrolling popovers, I don't need fading backgrounds.  I just want a simple way to get to the popover view.  Can anyone help???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the `CWPopup`, its simple and very easy to use just like you asked. You can find it here: https://github.com/cezarywojcik/CWPopup. I know you asked for storyboard, but there isn't a way to do that. Doing it in code is the only way, and it's very short. It's easier that you think.

I will break down the instructions for you.

1)
Import the directory CWPopup into your project. It contains the UIViewController categories.

2)
Add this with your imports: `#import "UIViewController+CWPopup.h"`

3) Make the popover show up:

```
 SamplePopupViewController *samplePopupViewController = [[SamplePopupViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SamplePopupViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentPopupViewController:samplePopupViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

4) Dismiss the Popover:

```
if (self.popupViewController != nil) {
[self dismissPopupViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

It's very simple. Just a few lines of code. Exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: I am able to open the popup quite nicely!  Wonderful.  But I'm having difficulty closing it.  I assume the dismiss popover code goes into a -(IBAction)dismissPop method.  Correct?

Comment: I have not done dismissing part yet, but this is a very nice solution and I thank you! :)

Comment: Dismissing the popup works great.  Very helpful.  But The blur effect is SO very extreme.  Is there a way to lessen the effect or eliminate it entirely?

Comment: Add this to your code: self.useBlurForPopup = NO; to eliminate it.

Comment: I am trying to understand your code... it is so complex!  I wish to not have it blur, or fade (darken) or have the popover scroll from the bottom... what methods are essential and what are not?

Comment: Ok, first try this and then I can explain. In the methods to show the popup and to dismiss the popup, set animated = NO. That will take away all the special effects that you don't want. Try it first, then if you want it to be explained, I can do it.

Comment: I understand now why you animated the popup when showing/dismissing.  It is ugly otherwise.  Thank you for explaining it though.  Is there a way to prevent darkening the background image?  (I apologize for asking you to dissect your code.)  - I did figure out how to eliminate the fadeview.

Comment: Well, the way that the github project was created makes you not able to change it. The person that created it did it intentionally in his code which you are not able to modify. You can only decide to use it or not. Sorry. One way you can create a popover view without the fading is to use Apple's UIAlertView. That is less complex and will not cause the background to fade.